# Getting highest value from one of many inputs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

so I have a simple input field:

```
<Input type="number" defaultValue="1" className="quantity"></Input>
```

but it is rendered by react as 12 different DOM elements. I need to get values from every input element or just the highest one if it is possible without getting every value. I was trying this:

```
var amount = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity')
```

but it outputs 'undefined'. Can you guys help here?

Comment: Usually in React you would not use DOM manipulation such as `document.getElementsByClassName()`. Instead if you rendered these 12 inputs from an array using `Array.prototype.map()` and track each value in the component(s) state, you would use state values to find the highest value. You need to share more about how your components are rendered and how you store the value of each input in state/store/etc.

Comment: If you bound the value on some state you can use `Math.max(...someArray)` but since you don't even have an onChange I don't think you [did it correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). Did you press F12 and see the warnings in the console?

Comment: `var amount = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity')` is going to set the `amount` as the NodeList of all the elements with that class.  Not their amounts.

Comment: could use `Math.max()`

Comment: try `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: My question, why is `Input` rendered as 12 different DOM elements? What are you importing that is causing this debacle?

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementsByClassName('quantity')` would only work if your input had a class attribute. `<input class="quantity">` It has a className attribute instead.

What you want to get all the inputs is

`document.querySelectorAll('[className~="quantity"]')`

Comment: Since `class` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, React uses `className` to allow you to create css classes

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
const maxValue = Math.max(...(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.quantity')).map(el => parseInt(el.value, 10))));
```